# Form Runner Persistence, Session Cookie

Tags: orbeon

We are integrating Form Runner/Builder into a project with a custom persistence layer.

Right now we have emptySessionPath="true" set to keep Orbeon and our Java app on the same session.

Orbeon is passing the jsessionid cookie in the persistence CRUD calls... except for the following instance....

1. User connects to our Java app and logs in, jsessionid cookie is set
2. User visits an existing form instance at /fr/OurApp/formtest/edit/3eb4ddcf03f2410084e5578adb1e2a7b (Session Cookie is present)
3. Persistence call is made to our custom persistence layer, but cookie is not forwarded

But, if the user was to first edit the form itself with a call to /fr/orbeon/builder/edit/f40efbe298204d16b6474fcdfea4c9fd which does pass the cookie to the persistence layer

At this point the user can go visit step 2 to complete the form instance and the cookie will persist. It seems that for some reason starting form builder is required to get the cookie to forward to the persistence layer when completing the form?

Any ideas on why the cookie isn't getting passed on step 2?

FYI this is on Orbeon 3.9 CE, also same behavior in 3.8. Using VMWare TC Server (Tomcat). Our java app is a Spring/Grails app.

Comment: Ok, in further investigation what seems to be happening is a call to /fr/app/form/edit/document does not set a session cookie, so there is no session cookie to forward to the persistence layer.

/fr/orbeon/builder/edit/document does set a session cookie so this call and any futher calls to /orbeon will pass a session cookie to the persistence layer.

Can someone point me to how I can get /fr/app/form/edit to set a session cookie?

Comment: Even forcing /fr/app/form/edit to set a cookie does nothing to the next persistence layer call. One further difference I see... There is an orbeon-username missing from the persistence header for /crud/app/form/form.xhtml?document=id. Once a call is made to /fr/orbeon/builder/edit/document then the cookie and headers are present on subsequent persistence calls... but not when starting off with a /fr/app/form/edit call.

Comment: Also, I don't see that any CRUD calls to retrieve file attachments include the session cookie. If someone was to upload an image to their form, getting the image back from the persistence layer will not pass along a session cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering if this might be what's described in [this bug](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=315104&group_id=168&atid=350207) (see in particular the comments). Basically, it doesn't seem like you can always reliably produce a `JSESSIONID` cookie. And as the bug says, we don't have a solution right now.

Do you think the bug corresponds to your case?

Comment: I don't think so, I have read this page and the Tomcat bug post a few times over the last week. It is not getting the jsessionid mixed up between an old instance. When fetching form file attachments it does not seem to be passing jsessionid at all.. nor is it when trying to first access /fr/app/form/edit

Comment: Mmh, ok! So that means that at this point I don't have the answer :( To figure it out will require reproducing the problem locally. And things have changed a bit post-3.9, so it would be good to reproduce with a nightly build if possible at all.

Comment: I'm testing it with the nightly build, will put together some kind of reproducible steps for you.

Comment: Where can I post a small .war persistence layer app for demonstration?

Comment: That reminds me of http://xkcd.com/949/ ;) Anyway if just a few MB you can send it by email to me (up to 25 MB).